# how to clear sessions

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, session, production

I am using rails 4.2, Mysql

Background:

I was using Webrick server to stage my website online. My database tables were populated and everything worked as i wanted to. I put few items in a cart to check my transaction and..... decided to switch my server to Unicorn. It took me sometime to understand how nginx, unicorn and ubuntu work together. While I was doing that I have decided to give myself a fresh start and (foolishly!) re-created my database schema.

Problem area:

When I restarted my app and clicked on 'Catalogue' menu the following exception appears:

[image]

I used

```
 rake tmp:sessions:clear & rake db:sessions:clear
```

Nothing had happen. Please help me to sort this out. Thank you.

Comment: Do you have ***cart record*** in `carts table` with `id = 46`?

Answer (score 0):

The quickest fix would be to reset that key on your session. Run Rails console and execute `session[:cart_id] = nil`.

Source: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#accessing-the-session

Comment: I am connected to a remote server via ssh.

Comment: That's okay, you can run `rails console` over SSH or from anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

To solve the 'cookie_store' problem I did:

1. On remote terminal (using ssh) type:

   rake secret

   to generate a secret token
2. open conf/initializers/secret_token.rb file and paste your secret token generated by rake there:

   MyApp::Application.config.secret_token ='f2629941....your secret token'
3. use 'sudo nano /etc/default/unicorn' cmd to open the 'unicorn' file  and set the 'SECRET_KEY_BASE' property to your secret token.
4. open config/secrets.yml file and check that the secret key base are the same in both files:

   **Do not keep production secrets in the repository,
   instead read values from the environment.

   production:

   secret_key_base: "<%= ENV['SECRET_KEY_BASE'] %>"

I hope somebody will find my answer useful.